# Load labels in pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot

I have data like following in Excel:

```
Code    Date        Count
--------------------------------
1001    20140601    11
1001    20140602    12
1001    20140603    9
1002    20140601    17
1002    20140602    13
1002    20140603    21
1003    20140601    12
1003    20140602    13
1003    20140603    11
```

I created pivot table, which for each `Date` show `Count`, so it is like following:

```
Labels  20140601    20140602    20140603
----------------------------------------
1001    11          12          9
1002    17          13          21
1003    12          13          11
```

I also have following table with data:

```
Code    Description
---------------------
1001    Something_1
1002    Something_2
1003    Something_3
```

Is there an easy way to replace code in pivot table with values from description? So my pivot table will look like:

```
Code         Date       Count
--------------------------------
Something_1  20140601   11
Something_1  20140602   12
Something_1  20140603   9
Something_2  20140601   17
Something_2  20140602   13
Something_2  20140603   21
Something_3  20140601   12
Something_3  20140602   13
Something_3  20140603   11
```

Comment: If you have PowerPivot you could do it, otherwise you can simply add lookup formulas to your first table and then that field will appear in your pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I've done it is to create the lookup in your source data and then simply change the label for your rows to the description instead of the code.